# Too much native call does not affect the speed

Tags: java, opengl, java-native-interface, lwjgl

Why these two pieces of codes, running on same conditions, does not have difference in amount of running time?

**Code 1**

```
static long time = 0;

static int n = 200;

static float[] vq = new float[200 * 200 * 200 * 3];
static int[] iq = new int[200 * 200 * 200];

static FloatBuffer verts = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vq.length);
static IntBuffer ind = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(iq.length);

static void draw() {

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                int index = (i * n * n) + (j * n) + k;
                vq[3 * index + 0] = i;
                vq[3 * index + 1] = j;
                vq[3 * index + 2] = k;

                iq[index] = index;
            }
        }
    }

    verts.put(vq);
    ind.put(iq);

    verts.flip();
    ind.flip();

    GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    GL11.glVertexPointer(3, 0, verts);

    GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_QUADS, ind);

    GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    long newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(newTime - time);
    time = newTime;
}
```

**Code 2**

```
static int n = 200;

static long time = 0;

static void draw() {

    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                GL11.glVertex3f(i, j, k);
            }
        }
    }

    GL11.glEnd();

    long newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(newTime - time);
    time = newTime;
}
```

The reason I think **Code 2** should be slower than **Code1**, is that it has near 8 millions native calls, but **Code 1** has just a few, and they do the same thing in result.

What is the reason, and how could I improve performance of my code?

Comment: How exactly to you call these methods? Is there a tight loop, a timer etc?

Comment: I call them in a Runnable in an asyncExec on display. When one call finished, I call it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code 1 includes copying your values into an array and then copying the array into native memory - if your n stays the same you can avoid this overhead by only doing it once.

Answer (score 0):

What matters here is what the OpenGL methods do, because if the `glVertexPointer` and `glDrawElements` methods of code 2 iterate through the supplied arrays, you end up with near as many iterations and methods as you do in code 1 where you handle the iterations on your own.  I'm not familiar with OpenGL, but I would assume `glVertexPointer` and `glDrawElements` need to iterate through the supplied arrays to create the equivalent of calling glVertex3f on each element.

In short, the amount of iterations and native method calls, whether in your java code or in the loaded libraries themselves, is approximately equivalent.

As for improving your code, I have nothing to say because I've never used OpenGL.

Comment: Are you sure about this expression? 
(Once a native method is loaded, invoking it takes a time nearly equivalent to invoking a non-native method)
Can you give any references please?

Comment: I believe I was incorrect on that statement actually.

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/jni/overhead.shtml